# PHP File download script does not work when clicked. But works when URL is accessed on the browser

Tags: php

I got a weird problem. I have a php code that downloads a zip file. The code is called from another php page when a link is clicked. The link passes 4 parameters. the first parameter is the file1, second is file2, 3rd is the id in the database, 4th is the location code. This works perfectly in one of my pages. But when I tried to call this from another page using different parameter, the script fails. Checked the file directory permissions and ownership, everything is okay. And the files I am trying to download are there. When I tried to access the link directly, it downloads the file. Weird... here is the download.php

```
if(isset($_GET['download_file'])&&isset($_GET['download_file2'])&&isset($_GET['id'])&&isset($_GET['loc'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $loc=$_GET['loc'];
    switch ($loc) {
        case 1:
            $path = "../uploads/b2ho/";
            break;
        case 2:
            $path = "../uploads/ho2b/";
            break;
        default:
            exit;
    }
    $dt_file = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})", '', $_GET['download_file']);
    $dt_file = filter_var($dt_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $fd_file = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})", '', $_GET['download_file2']);
    $fd_file = filter_var($fd_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $dt_fullPath = $path.$dt_file;
    $fd_fullpath = $path.$fd_file;
    $zipname = 'BISAR.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFile($dt_fullPath,$dt_file);
    $zip->addFile($fd_fullpath,$fd_file);
    $zip->close();

    if (file_exists($zipname)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zipname));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($zipname);
        exit;
        $x=true;
    }

    if($loc==1){
        if($x==true){
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE rfc_bisar_b2h_upl_log SET bisar_proc_status='Pending',bisar_proc_down_date='$date',bisar_down_by='$userid' where bisar_upl_id=?");
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
            $stmt->execute();
            mysqli_close($conn);
            header("Refresh:0");
        }
    }
    if($loc==3){
        if($x==true){
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE rfc_bisar_h2b_upl_log SET bisar_proc_status='Pending',bisar_proc_down_date='$date',bisar_down_by='$userid' where bisar_upl_id=?");
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
            $stmt->execute();
            mysqli_close($conn);
            header("Refresh:0");
        }
    }
    if(file_exists($zipname)){
        unlink($zipname);
    }
}
```

Comment: change $zipname = 'BISAR'.zip'; to  $zipname = 'BISAR.zip';

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove that. i was editing the filename to remove the actual filename I used in my code. Yes, but still does not work

Comment: Also always check the PHP logs.

Comment: Please note that this download.php file works perfecty on other page calls using ahref. When I use it on a different page passing a different parameter. It does not work. It only only works when I access the link  manually

Comment: You need to show HTML/JS code that calls this script

Comment: Please provide links for working and broken solutions. Without input parameters provided code can not help us.

Comment: check page roytuts.com/force-download-a-file-using-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys. Resolved this issue by adding a target="_blank" on my anchor tag where I call the download.php . It is really weird why php does not allow me to download the file on the same page but instead requires me to open a new tab.

Comment: Its not related to php. This is browser behavior

Comment: Probably... I used Edge, firefox and chrome for testing. all browsers exhibits the same behavior. Or is there something wrong with the headers I used?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check broken link parameters. I think that link is invalid (one of query string parameters has invalid name and isset condition does not pass)

Answer (score 0):

1. change `$zipname = 'BISAR'.zip';` to `$zipname = 'BISAR.zip';`
2. at top you have locations 1 and 2 and at the bottom 1 and 3
3. use `case` or `else` instead of bottom location if case
4. Notice: Undefined variable: date
5. Undefined variable: userid
6. Call to undefined method `PDOStatement::bind_param()` should be `bindParam`
7. change`where bisar_upl_id=?` to `where bisar_upl_id=:bisar_upl_id`
8. change `$stmt->bindParam('s ',$id)` to `$stmt->bindParam(':bisar_upl_id',$id)`
9. mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given. Should be $stmt->closeCursor(); butt this is not even required

**DB table create statement:**

```
CREATE TABLE `rfc_bisar_b2h_upl_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bisar_proc_status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bisar_proc_down_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bisar_down_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bisar_upl_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**DB table fill:**

```
INSERT INTO `rfc_bisar_b2h_upl_log` (`id`, `bisar_upl_id`) VALUES ('1', '1');
```

**and here is working php code:**

```
    $_GET['download_file'] = 'xxxx.php';
    $_GET['download_file2'] = 'xxxx2.php';
    $_GET['id'] = 1;
    $_GET['loc'] = 1;
    $date = 1;
    $userid = 1;

   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);


    if (isset($_GET['download_file']) && isset($_GET['download_file2']) && isset($_GET['id'])){

        $id  = $_GET['id'];
        $loc = $_GET['loc'];
        switch ($loc) {
            case 1:
                $path = "../uploads/b2ho/";
                break;
            case 2:
                $path = "../uploads/ho2b/";
                break;
            default:
                die('wrong location passed');
        }
        $dt_file     = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})", '', $_GET['download_file']);
        $dt_file     = filter_var($dt_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $fd_file     = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})", '', $_GET['download_file2']);
        $fd_file     = filter_var($fd_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $dt_fullPath = $path.$dt_file;
        $fd_fullpath = $path.$fd_file;
        $zipname = 'BISAR.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        $zip->addFile($dt_fullPath,$dt_file);
        $zip->addFile($fd_fullpath,$fd_file);
        $zip->close();

        if (file_exists($zipname)) {

            $quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($zipname), '"\\'));
            $size   = filesize($zipname);

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
            flush();
            readfile($zipname);
            $x=true;
        }

    if($loc==1){
        if($x==true){
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE rfc_bisar_b2h_upl_log SET bisar_proc_status='Pending',bisar_proc_down_date='$date',bisar_down_by='$userid' where bisar_upl_id=:bisar_upl_id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':bisar_upl_id',$id);
            $stmt->execute();
            header("Refresh:0");
        }
    }else{
        if($loc==2){
            if($x==true){
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE rfc_bisar_b2h_upl_log SET bisar_proc_status='Pending',bisar_proc_down_date='$date',bisar_down_by='$userid' where bisar_upl_id=:bisar_upl_id");
                $stmt->bindParam(':bisar_upl_id',$id);
                $stmt->execute();
                header("Refresh:0");
            }
        }

    }
    if(file_exists($zipname)){
        unlink($zipname);
    }
}
```